# Can't get HTTP headers from request

Tags: nim-lang

I'm trying to get the headers from a HTTP request. I've tried `echo`ing them, only to get a compile error. I've tried looping through the headers as well. My code is:

```
var packet = newMultipartData()
packet["username"] = username
packet["password"] = password

var response = post(BASE & "users/login", multipart=packet)
echo response.headers
```

And the error I'm getting is: `Error: type mismatch: got (HttpHeaders)`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj Oops, forgot to include that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - Turns out I can call the one I want from the list. Ex: `response.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"]`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not work because there is no $ proc defined for **HttpHeaders**:

```
let headers = newHttpHeaders()
headers["foo"] = "bar"
headers["foo2"] = "bar2"
echo headers["foo"]  # compiles
echo headers         # does _not_ compile
```

We can quickly implement an own $ proc ourselves:

```
proc `$`(h: HttpHeaders): string =
  result = "{"
  for key, value in h:
    if result.len > 1: result.add(", ")
      result.add(key)
    result.add(": ")
    result.add(value)
  result.add("}")
```

The implementation is based on https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/master/lib/pure/collections/tables.nim#L333.  Because HttpHeaders is just a type to a table, we can simply reuse the existing proc.

```
type
  HttpHeaders* = ref object
    table*: TableRef[string, seq[string]]
```